# Session handling in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, web-applications

How do you maintain session (set session id, get session id) in a multiple user (admin,user) logged in application in CodeIgniter?

I am using this `if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == '')`. But this is not working.

Thanks

Comment: How you are using? Can you be more clear with your original code?

Comment: you can try with if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')).

Comment: I have two types of user. 1.admin 2. user. If I logged in as user, then use the url of admin then application showing admin is also logged in. Even If I use below code 

 `public function __construct()
 {
  if($this->session->userdata('user_role') == 'admin')
  {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user_model');
  }
  else
  {
   redirect('administrator');
  }
 }`

I am getting error like this 


**A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Users::$session

Filename: controllers/users.php

Line Number: 6**

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!=FALSE) {

        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    }
```

so u can find the current userdata

Answer (score 0):

First check out weather u have load the session library..

If your validating the blank value then ur wrong, use this

```
// to set the session data
$this->session->set_userdata('name', 'value');  // note u can also pass array

if(isset($this->session->userdata('name'))){

   //to read session data
   $this->session->userdata('name'); // note u can also pass array

   //to unset or delete
   $this->session->unset_userdata('name');
```

}

Comment: I have two types of user. 1.admin 2. user. If I logged in as user, then use the url of admin then application showing admin is also logged in. Even If I use below code public function __construct() { if($this->session->userdata('user_role') == 'admin') { parent::__construct(); $this->load->model('user_model'); } else { redirect('administrator'); } } I am getting error like this A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Users::$session Filename: controllers/users.php Line Number: 6

Comment: Modified the following things 
-- do not place the class construct twice, 
-- if your defining the private function i.e using function __functionName (){  }  then do not prefix it by public.


function someOtherMeaningfullFunctionName() { 

  if($this->session->userdata('user_role') == 'admin') { 
   $this->load->model('user_model'); 
  } else { 
   redirect('administrator'); 
  } 
 }

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your session before like,

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', 'value');
```

Then check whether the session is set properly,

```
if(isset($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {

      if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == '') {
           // Your Code
      }
}
```

If the above `isset()` returns **false**, then your session is not set correctly. Check that.

Answer (score 0):

Please load the **session library**

Depending if you auto-load the session library or not, we will need to include:

```
    $this->load->library('session');
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', 'some_value');
```

and to check whether session is set or not just use

```
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
      //code for logged in 
   }
```

if still not work please **try by clearing browser cache**

I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check whether the session item you are trying to retrieve exists or not, then compare it to a value you want to.
Try this:

```
if( $this->session->userdata("logged_in") !== FALSE ){
    if( $this->session->userdata("logged_in") == "admin" ){
        //logged in as admin
    }elseif( $this->session->userdata("logged_in") == "user" ){
        //logged in as user
    }
}
```

One more thing, the

```
parent::__constructor();
```

line should always be the first line of code in your constructor function, otherwise, you will experience lots of errors later in your code